# Placing electric stations NP Hard problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, graph-theory, np

We have a problem (stated to be NP Hard) as follows:

> Given a connected undirected unweighted graph G = (V, E) and a set of routes (a sequence of vertices) from homes to offices (there can be multiple routes starting from homes, and multiple routes ending at offices), we want to place minimum electric charging stations such that all routes are covered at least once. We cannot place stations at homes or offices.

The below image shows a possible input (please ignore the weights):
[image: Stations Input]

Where the house icons are homes and brick wall icons are offices.

The optimal above is placing stations at vertices *R* and *D*.

Finding the optimal solution is said to be an NP Hard problem.

I have an approach, which goes something like this:

```
Let S be empty set of charging stations (vertices)
Let R be set of all given routes, r_i = <v_0, v_1 ... v_j> where v_0 is of type "home" and v_j is of type "office"
Let Vdeg be array of integers of size |V| intially set to 0
For r in R:
    Increment Vdeg of every vertex v in r
while R is not empty:
    Sort vertices by decreasing Vdeg
    Let maxDeg be maximum degree vertex in V
    Add maxDeg to S
    for all routes r in R which contains maxDeg
        R = R\{r}
        Decrement Vdeg for maxDeg
```

The above algorithm runs in (I believe) polynomial time, and also (I believe) gives the optimal solution.

The full implementation is given below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// A Graph Vertice
struct node {
    int id;
    std::string type;
    std::string name;
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const node& n) {
    return out << "{ " << n.type << ", " << n.name << " }";
}

// A Graph Edge
struct edge {
    node * from;
    node * to;
    int weight;
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const edge& e) {
    return out << "{ " << *e.from << ", " << *e.to << ", " << e.weight << " }";
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<edge>& graph) {
    out << "{ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < graph.size(); ++i) {
        out << graph[i] << ", ";
    }
    return out << "\b\b }";
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<node*>& vertices) {
    out << "{ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); ++i) {
        out << "\n  " << *vertices[i] << ", ";
    }
    return out << "\b\b \n}";
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<edge*>& graph) {
    out << "{ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < graph.size(); ++i) {
        out << "\n  " << *graph[i] << ", ";
    }
    return out << "\b\b \n}";
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<std::vector<edge*>>& graph) {
    out << "{";
    for(int i = 0; i < graph.size(); ++i) {
        out << "\n  " << graph[i] << ", ";
    }
    return out << "\b\b \n}";
}

// A Vdeg which also stores id and routes intersecting on it
struct vertice_degrees {
    int id;
    int degree;
    std::vector<int> intersecting;
};

// Greater than operator overloaded for sorting Vdegs by degree
bool operator >(const vertice_degrees& vd1, const vertice_degrees& vd2) {
    return vd1.degree > vd2.degree;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<vertice_degrees>& vd) {
    out << "{ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < vd.size(); ++i) {
        out << "{ " << vd[i].id << ", " << vd[i].degree << ", { ";
        for(int j = 0; j < vd[i].intersecting.size(); ++j) {
            out << vd[i].intersecting[j] << ", ";
        }
        out << "\b\b }, ";
    }
    return out << "\b\b }";
}

void print_routes(const std::string label, const std::vector<int> routes_to_cover, const std::vector<std::vector<edge*>> routes, const std::string label_after) {
    std::cout << label << "{ ";
    for(int i = 0; i < routes_to_cover.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << routes[routes_to_cover[i]] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\b\b }" << label_after;
}

int main() {
        
    // List of vertices in graph
    node vertices[] = {
        node{ 0, "House", "A" },
        node{ 1, "House", "B" },
        node{ 2, "House", "F" },
        node{ 3, "House", "N" },
        node{ 4, "House", "S" },
        node{ 5, "Office", "H" },
        node{ 6, "Office", "K" },
        node{ 7, "Office", "L" },
        node{ 8, "Office", "P" },
        node{ 9, "Office", "T" },
        node{ 10, "None", "C" },
        node{ 11, "None", "D" },
        node{ 12, "None", "E" },
        node{ 13, "None", "G" },
        node{ 14, "None", "I" },
        node{ 15, "None", "J" },
        node{ 16, "None", "M" },
        node{ 17, "None", "O" },
        node{ 18, "None", "Q" },
        node{ 19, "None", "R" },
        node{ 20, "None", "U" }
    };
    // Length of vertices array
    const int vertice_count = sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(node);

    // List of edges in graph
    std::vector<edge> graph = {
        edge{ &vertices[0], &vertices[12], 3 },
        edge{ &vertices[12], &vertices[15], 3 },
        edge{ &vertices[15], &vertices[19], 4 },
        edge{ &vertices[19], &vertices[20], 5 },
        edge{ &vertices[20], &vertices[9], 5 },
        edge{ &vertices[1], &vertices[10], 4 },
        edge{ &vertices[10], &vertices[11], 2 },
        edge{ &vertices[11], &vertices[5], 2 },
        edge{ &vertices[2], &vertices[12], 4 },
        edge{ &vertices[12], &vertices[14], 4 },
        edge{ &vertices[14], &vertices[11], 3 },
        edge{ &vertices[11], &vertices[13], 7 },
        edge{ &vertices[13], &vertices[6], 2 },
        edge{ &vertices[3], &vertices[19], 3 },
        edge{ &vertices[19], &vertices[16], 5 },
        edge{ &vertices[16], &vertices[17], 2 },
        edge{ &vertices[17], &vertices[7], 2 },
        edge{ &vertices[4], &vertices[19], 4 },
        edge{ &vertices[19], &vertices[17], 6 },
        edge{ &vertices[17], &vertices[18], 4 },
        edge{ &vertices[18], &vertices[8], 3 }
        // Remaining edges are not on routes, and hence are inconsequential and can be omitted
    };
    
    // List of routes
    std::vector<std::vector<edge*>> routes_arr = {
        std::vector<edge*>{ &graph[0], &graph[1], &graph[2], &graph[3], &graph[4] },
        std::vector<edge*>{ &graph[5], &graph[6], &graph[7] },
        std::vector<edge*>{ &graph[8], &graph[9], &graph[10], &graph[11], &graph[12] },
        std::vector<edge*>{ &graph[13], &graph[14], &graph[15], &graph[16] },
        std::vector<edge*>{ &graph[17], &graph[18], &graph[19], &graph[20] }
    };

    std::cout << routes_arr;

    // Vdeg list of size V, and initialised
    std::vector<vertice_degrees> vertice_degrees_arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < vertice_count; ++i) {
        vertice_degrees_arr.push_back(vertice_degrees{ i, 0 });
    }

    // Add all the routes the vertice is part of for each vertice in Vdeg
    for(int i = 0; i < routes_arr.size(); ++i) {
        for(int j = 0, k; j < routes_arr[i].size(); ++j) {
            vertice_degrees& vd = vertice_degrees_arr[routes_arr[i][j]->from->id];
            vd.degree += 1;
            for(k = 0; k < vd.intersecting.size(); ++k) {
                if(vd.intersecting[k] == i) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            vd.intersecting.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    // routes_to_cover is remaining routes left to cover, list of route indexes
    std::cout << "\nFilled: \n" << vertice_degrees_arr;
    std::vector<int> routes_to_cover;
    for(int i = 0; i < routes_arr.size(); ++i) {
        routes_to_cover.push_back(i);
    }
    // Final resulting S
    std::vector<node*> stations_placed_at;

    // While there are routes still to cover
    while(routes_to_cover.size() > 0) {

        // Insertion Sort the Vdeg by degree
        for(int i = 1, j; i < vertice_degrees_arr.size(); ++i) {
            const vertice_degrees vd = vertice_degrees_arr[i];
            for(j = i; j > 0 && vertice_degrees_arr[j-1] > vd; --j) {
                vertice_degrees_arr[j] = vertice_degrees_arr[j-1];
            }
            vertice_degrees_arr[j] = vd;
        }

        // Get all the routes intersecting at v, add v to S
        std::vector<int> covered_routes = vertice_degrees_arr[vertice_degrees_arr.size()-1].intersecting;
        stations_placed_at.push_back(&vertices[ vertice_degrees_arr[vertice_degrees_arr.size()-1].id ]);
        std::cout << "\nSorted: \n" << vertice_degrees_arr;

        // Remove routes intersecting at v from all Vdeg, decrease degree for next iteration
        for(int i = 0; i < vertice_degrees_arr.size(); ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < vertice_degrees_arr[i].intersecting.size(); ++j) {
                for(int k = 0; k < covered_routes.size(); ++k)
                if(vertice_degrees_arr[i].intersecting[j] == covered_routes[k]) {
                    vertice_degrees_arr[i].intersecting.erase(vertice_degrees_arr[i].intersecting.begin() + j--);
                    vertice_degrees_arr[i].degree -= 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        std::cout << "\nCleaned:\n" << vertice_degrees_arr;

        // Remove covered routes this iteration from routes_to_cover
        for(int i = 0; i < routes_to_cover.size(); ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < covered_routes.size(); ++j) {
                if(routes_to_cover[i] == covered_routes[j]) {
                    routes_to_cover.erase(routes_to_cover.begin() + i--);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        print_routes("\nRemaining routes: ", routes_to_cover, routes_arr, "\n");
    }

    std::cout << "\nFinal Nodes: " << stations_placed_at;

    return 0;
}
```

So what's wrong with this solution?

Is it:

1. Not polynomial? or
2. Not optimal?

If the former, can you explain how?

If the latter, can you provide a counter?

Comment: Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches.

Comment: It's not optimal. There's a straightforward reduction from hitting set, and I'm sure that an algorithm this simple will struggle with the instances that prove an Ω(log n)-factor integrality gap.

Comment: @itprorh66 how is it an opinion based or subjective question? It is either optimal or not. Polynomial or not. The complexity is not subjective either.

Comment: @itprorh66 the subject matter here is one that may sound subjective but has a specific mathematical implementation that is not subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is not optimal, as can be seen by reduction from the [exact 3-cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover).

To see that, let's start with a number of homes that is a multiple of 3.  Add a single office.  And for each 3-set in our cover we add one vertex with routes from the 3 homes in the 3-set to this vertex, then to the office.  It is easy to verify that if an exact 3-cover exists, the set of vertices associated with that exact 3-cover is an optimal arrangement of gas stations.  So your problem requires being able to find exact 3-covers.

But your algorithm is greedy and its very first choice is a random guess with no way to decide that any vertex is better than any other.  If it first guesses a 3-set that is not in any exact 3-cover, then you won't find the optimal solution.

Comment: Are you taking routes with no intersection? Otherwise exact 3 cover wouldn't be optimal? Is it possible to add an example?

Comment: @JaideepShekhar Dang it, I had misread the problem description.  I was supplying an answer where every possible house/office combination had a route with a gas station.  And not every possible route did.  My bad.  But I'm glad you were able to find a way to a full solution from that!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after reading up on [Exact 3 set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) and the helpful answer by [@btilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585411/btilly), I have finally been able to come up with a counter to my algorithm.

The intuition is that the algorithm works for inputs which don't have the same degree. Hence, try making the same degree.

The counter is as follows.

Given below graph:

[image: Input Graph]

With the following routes:

```
R1: A, C, F, J, L
R2: B, C, D
R3: E, F, H, K
R4: I, J, H, G
```

The optimal is selecting the vertices *C* and *H* like so:

[image: Optimal Solution]

But if our algorithm picks *F* first (as degrees are same) like so:

[image: Greedy Solution Pt1]

Then we are forced to pick *C* and one of *H* or *J* as follows:

[image: Greedy Solution Pt2]

Which is obviously not the optimal solution.